# summation of 1000 different random numbers between 80-130?

Tags: python, random

I want to get the summation of 1000 different random numbers. Range of random number should be between 80 - 130 and they must be floating points not integers. I am new to python and don't have clue where to start this from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there you go:

```
import random
sum(random.random()*50 + 80 for _ in range(1000))
```

but you'd better using the statistical formula for the sum of independent variables, it would be more efficient if you need more than 1000 numbers (and at that point you can even approximate it with a gaussian).

Comment: @fortran: You are correct to point out the inefficiency of this method. You can produce the answer by generating 1 random number instead of N. But what does it have to do with binomial distribution? Just apply CLT, and the answer is a random drawn from a distribution with mean=(80 + 130)/2 * N, variance=math.sqrt(N) * 1/12 * pow((130 - 80), 2). But the question does not seem to have anything to do with python. Or statistics.

Comment: my statistics are rusty, I recalled 'sum of independent variables = binomial' xD

Answer (score 2):

130 - 80 = 50

```
>>> import random
>>> sum(80 + random.random() * 50 for i in range(1000))
104845.89616338456
```

**UPDATE**

Using [random.uniform](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random#random.uniform) is more simple.

```
>>> import random
>>> sum(random.uniform(80, 130) for i in range(1000))
105084.04238138645
```

Comment: .. why not simply `random.uniform(80, 130)`?